# How to properly format the string in a new column of DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with two columns `col1` and `col2` (Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11). I need to create a new column in the following format:

```
=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/AAA_BBB.jpg", 1)
```

where `AAA` is the value of `col1` and `BBB` is the value of `col2` for a given row.

The problem is that I do not know how to properly handle `"`. I tried this:

```
df = df.withColumn($"url",=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/"+col("col1") + "_"+col("col2")+".jpg", 1))"
```

**UPDATE:**

It compiles ok now, but column values are not inserted in a string. Instead of column values, I see the text `col1` and `col2`.

```
df = df.withColumn("url_rec",lit("=path('http://mywebsite.com/photo/"+col("col1")+"_"+col("col1")+".jpg', 1)"))
```

I get this:

```
=path('http://mywebsite.com/photo/col1_col1.jpg', 1)
```

Comment: have you try escaping quotes in the middle ? such as "=path(\"http://mywebsite.com/photo/"

Comment: @Fabich: Please see my update. I was able to compile the code. But when I run it, I get strings without the values of columns inserted in these strings.

Comment: You'll have to use multiple `concat` one after another if you wan to change it for each row.

Comment: @philantrovert: Ok, I see. Now it works. Thanks. Could you please put your recommendation into the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you can either use `concat` multiple times like :

```
d.show
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|AAA|BBB|
+---+---+

d.withColumn("URL" , 
   concat(
       concat(
           concat(
               concat(lit("""=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/""" ), $"a") ,
               lit("_") ) , $"b" 
           ) 
           , lit(""".jpg", 1) """) 
         ).as[String].first

// String = "=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/AAA_BBB.jpg", 1) "
```

Or you can map over the dataframe to append a new column ( which is cleaner than the `concat` method )

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val urlRdd = d.map{ x => 
     Row.fromSeq(x.toSeq ++ Seq(s"""=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/${x.getAs[String]("a")}_${x.getAs[String]("b")}.jpg", 1)""")) 
    }

val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(urlRdd, d.schema.add("url", StringType) )

newDF.map(_.getAs[String]("url")).first
// String = =path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/AAA_BBB.jpg", 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I put my answer here for anybody else. You can use the `format_string` function

```
scala> df1.show()
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
| AAA| BBB|
+----+----+

scala> df1.withColumn(
            "URL",
            format_string(
                """=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/%s_%s.jpg", 1)""", 
                col("col1"), 
                col("col2")
            )
        ).show(truncate = false)

+----+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|col1|col2|URL                                               |
+----+----+--------------------------------------------------+
|AAA |BBB |=path("http://mywebsite.com/photo/AAA_BBB.jpg", 1)|
+----+----+--------------------------------------------------+
```